# Inverse Continuous Wavelet Transform off by constant factors

Tags: continuous-signals

I am implementing a continuous wavelet transform and its inverse using morlet wavelets. When I compute the inverse, the resulting signal is off by some constant factor (but otherwise correct). Depending on which frequencies of wavelet I use for the transforms, the resulting signal is off by a different constant factor.

[image]

I am using the formula above for my inverse transform, but I am missing the 1/C before the double integral. I think this 1/C is the source of my issues, but I cannot find a definition that I can understand or implement, so any help in solving my situation would be appreciated.

Thanks!